# What type of guitar is pictured here?

Tags: electric-guitar

What type of guitar this? This is the only picture available.

[image: unknown guitar]

Comment: There are numerous pictures on the Rickenbacker site. The R is a good clue.

Comment: How is someone supposed to know to go to the Rickenbacker site to find those pictures?  And I don't see an "R."  Even if I did, how would I know that that stood for "Rickenbacker?"

Comment: @WayneConrad: It doesn't jump out at you, but there's a nice shiny R under the person's right thumb, incorporated into the...whateveritscalled.

Comment: OK, Now I see it.  Weird how plain it is now when it was invisible to me before.

Comment: @TonyK that's a tailpiece

Answer (score 11):

It look very much like a Rickenbacker, more specifically a 340-Mapleglo (see images [here](https://reverb.com/p/rickenbacker-340-mapleglo-2008)). And regarding the type of guitar: it is a six-string hollow-body electric guitar.